# How to use user defined variable names in a linux command?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scp

I am new to writing scripts. I need to write a script to download files from server and store it in a directory defined dynamically using linux's date-time.

Here is what it looks like

```
dir_path="/Users/me/Downloads/stuff/data_vm/"  
pem_path="/Users/me/Downloads/mypem"
```

Now I define the directory name

```
dir_name="backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)"
```

Then I concatenate the `dir_path` and `dir_name`

```
final_path="${dir_path}${dir_name}"
```

Now I create the directory on this path

```
mkdir "${final_path}"
```

Now I am having issue in using the variables defined above in my `scp` command. This is what I do

```
scp -i "${pem_path}"  -r root@11.555.00.222:/home/ec2-user/stats/dom/files/  "$(final_path)"
```

It is able to create the directory but I get `command not found` for the line that contains `scp` command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes I do. scp runs fine if I don't use variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `"$(final_path)"` should be `"$final_path"` (or `"${final_path}"` if you like curly braces).

With `"$(final_path)"`, the shell would see `final_path` as a command to run in a command substitution (a substitution of a command's output into a string; you use this with `date` earlier). You would the expect to get an error on the form

```
sh: final_path: command not found
```

Also note that the `${variable}` syntax is only really *necessary* when you want use the expansion `$variable` inside a string where you concatenate it with a character that is a valid character in a variable's name, as in `"${variable}_"` or `"${variable}hello"`.  In all other cases, it's enough to use `"$variable"`, but this may come down to personal habit.

Comment: yes you are right! After I changed `$(final_path)` to `${final_path}` and did similarly operation to `pem_path` in the `scp` command, it ran fine. Thanks!